# Why does SQLite work on CephFS but not NFS

Tags: nfs, sqlite, ceph

They're both network based filesystem protocols.  So why can I mount SQLite databases on CephFS, but not using NFS?

I've had no issues with SQLite on CephFS, but when I mount stuff that uses SQLite on NFS, I constantly get 'database is locked' errors.

Comment: SQLPite is file-system agnostic. The device you're using is mounting the NFS partition read-only.

Comment: Which NFS version are you using, and does [SQLite FAQ item #5](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5) provide the answer?

Comment: @user1686 Currently NFSv3 with locking enabled (and rpc-statd enabled on server).  I've also tried it with NFSv4.  The program using SQLite is Radarr.